# Multiple collections of same type in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have these two very simple classes.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Person> Teachers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> Students { get; set; }
}
```

I would like EF to keep `Teachers` seperated from `Students` however they both get jumbled into a `Person` table with no way to distinguish between them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways to do it;

**first** : use a tag or enums in the `Person` object

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public bool IsFaculty { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public enum PersonType { Teacher, Student }; 

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public PersonType PropPersonType { get; set; }
}
```

**second** : work object oriented with inheritance. This method has my preference because it's easy to manage and expand if you want to expand it.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}


public class Student : Person
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    // other student related fiels.
}


public class Teacher : Person
{
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    // other teacher related fields
}
```

Your `Group` is then

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have got the first use case and I'm using an enum- how do I let entity framework (core) know that I want to use the enum to differentiate?

Comment: Although both are valid in different cases, I would strongly encourage people to use the inheritance model: Teachers and Students are both types of Person, but a Person may not always be a Teacher or a Student. Maybe this is the case now, but what happens in future if you need to introduce a "Parent" type, for example? Secondly: if you were instead to use enums to discriminate the type, there would be no "natural" type enforcement for the Teachers and Students properties; it would be very easy to accidentally add a Student to the Teacher collection, adn vice versa. Inheritance resolves this.

Answer (score 1):

Separate in two different classes, and then inherit both of them with Person, because all the teachers and students are Persons, but not all Persons are teachers and students.

```
public class Person
{
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
}

public class Student : Person
{
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I have considered that as an option, but I'd really like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit different case (when class is holding reference to two identical objects), but can be helpful:

```
    public class Mission
{
    //DB objects
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SourceLocationId {get; set}
    public int DestinationLocationId {get; set}

    //Virtual objects
    public virtual Location SourceLocation { get; set; }
    public virtual Location DestinationLocation { get; set; }

}

public class Location
{
    //DB objects
    public int Id {get;set;}

    //Virtual objects
    public virtual ICollection<Mission> SourceMissions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Mission> DestinationMissions { get; set; }
}
```

Then all you need to do is bind it properly in **OnModelCreating**:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Mission>()
        .HasOptional(m => m.SourceLocation)   //Optional or Required
        .WithMany(sm => sm.SourceMissions)
        .HasForeignKey(to => to.SourceLocationId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Mission>()
        .HasOptional(m => m.DestinationLocation)   //Optional or Required
        .WithMany(sm => sm.DestinationMissions)
        .HasForeignKey(to => to.DestinationLocationId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some flag to distinguising them (I can't really belive you that can't). And after you can use `TPH` inheritance approach. See more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793152.ASPX) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

To have **Teachers** and **Students** in two **separate** tables inherit from an abstract base:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    // other student related fiels.
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    // other teacher related fields
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```