# Is it possible to have multiple collection properties of entities with the same base class (TPH) inside one entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In my project I use Entity Framework core 2.0.
The next code is slightly simplified. There are such models:

```
public class Site
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AudioLink> AudioLinks { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VideoLink> VideoLinks { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Link
{
    public int Id { get; set; }         
    public string Href { get; set; }

    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public Site Site { get; set; }
}

public class AudioLink : Link
{
}

public class VideoLink : Link
{
}
```

I use Fluent API to configure relationships:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AudioLink> AudioLinks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VideoLink> VideoLinks { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Link>()
            .HasDiscriminator<byte>("LinkType")
            .HasValue<AudioLink>(1)
            .HasValue<VideoLink>(2);

        builder.Entity<Site >().HasMany(s => s.VideoLinks)
            .WithOne(l => l.Site)
            .HasForeignKey(l => l.SiteId);

        builder.Entity<Site >().HasMany(s => s.AudioLinks)
            .WithOne(l => l.Site)
            .HasForeignKey(l => l.SiteId);
    }
}
```

It look's like the migration and database are created correctly.
But when I create new Site object:

```
var site = new Site(){Id = 1, Name = "SiteA"}
var audioLink = new AudioLink(){Id = 1, Href = "abc", Site = site};

context.Sites.Add(site);
context.SaveChanges();
context.AudioLinks.Add(audioLink);// exception occurs
context.SaveChanges();
```

the next exception is thrown "Unable to cast object of type 'ApplicationCore.Entities.AudioLink' to type 'ApplicationCore.Entities.VideoLink'."
Could you tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You either refuse inheritance, or use the collection type for the base type.

Comment: The calls to `HasMany` are both wrong, and should not compile.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @hVostt! Do you mean that I should use ICollection<Link> Links property instead of 2 properties in Site class to keep inheritance and one table?

Comment: @OL Oh sure! Otherwise, why do you need this inheritance? :)

Comment: And, I highly recommend using ICollection instead of List in public classes, this is important.

Comment: Thanks @M.Aroosi, I've corrected the text

Comment: @hVostt you are right. That should be the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance does not change the rule that single reference navigation property can be mapped only to a single inverse collection navigation property.

In fact what is happening is that the second `HasMany` / `WithOne` overrides the previous one (probably a bug, should throw exception), so the `Link.Site` is mapped to the `Site.AudioLinks` (not that the `Site` is a property of the base entity `Site`, hence is shared by `AudioLink` and `VideoLink`).

So you either have to remove the `Site` and `SiteId` properties from the base class and put them in the derived classes (which will introduce 2 FK relationships), or better use a single collection navigation property of the base type:

```
public class Site
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping:

```
builder.Entity<Site>().HasMany(s => s.Links)
   .WithOne(l => l.Site)
   .HasForeignKey(l => l.SiteId);
```

You can always use the `OfType()` operator to get the `AudioLinks` or `VideoLinks` from `Links` in both LINQ to Entities query or LINQ to Objects after `Site` materialization.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628139/multiple-collections-of-same-type-in-entity-framework?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) similar behavior could be implemented in Entity Framework. Is such approach going to be implemented in next versions of EF core?

Comment: I don't think the post is correct. EF6 and EF Core are the same in that regard, probably the author of the accepted answer didn't mean using EF inheritance strategy, just base class and 2 totally separate tables,